# Perl - Find, Format and Replace strings in a file

Tags: perl, replace, find, format, substring

I have a csv file in which I store, among other things, time under the format **h:m:s** and I want to turn those times into numbers representing the total seconds. Example if I have **1:02:34** I would want it replaced with 1*3600 + 2*60 + 34 = **3754**.

What I'm trying to do is the following:

1. find all the times under the format h:m:s
2. perform formatting operation which we turn the time in seconds
3. replace the time under format h:m:s with the formatted number in seconds

Of course I would like to make all these changes while traversing through the file only once. But I'm stuck on the replacing and the writing back to the file with the formatted variable part.
If anybody could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated. If doing this in one go is possible of course.

Thanks,
CJ

This is how the data looks:

```
Column,Column,Column,Column,Column,Column,Column,Column,Column
1408319018,0:0:28,0:00:00,0:01:00,0:00:00,0:06:16,NA:NA:NA,0:07:32,0:8:0
1408313536,0:2:6,0:00:01,0:01:00,0:00:00,0:06:20,NA:NA:NA,0:07:40,0:9:46
1408319031,0:0:24,0:00:00,0:01:07,0:00:00,0:07:06,NA:NA:NA,0:08:30,0:8:54
1408319018,0:2:21,0:00:01,0:00:54,0:00:00,0:00:37,NA:NA:NA,0:01:51,0:4:12
1408319037,1:51:13,0:00:01,0:01:13,0:00:01,0:18:09,NA:NA:NA,0:19:41,2:10:54
1408319031,1:58:18,0:00:01,0:00:55,0:00:00,0:00:18,NA:NA:NA,0:01:30,1:59:48
```

And this is how my code looks so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
#use warnings;

my $line;
my $file = "bla.csv";
my ($formatTime0,$formatTime1,$formatTime2,$formatTime3,$formatTime4,$formatTime5,$formatTime6);

open(my $OUTPUT, '+<'. $file);

while( $line = <$OUTPUT> ) {

    $formatTime0 = formatTime( ($line =~ /,(\d:\d*:\d*)/g)[0] );
    $formatTime1 = formatTime( ($line =~ /,(\d:\d*:\d*)/g)[1] );
    $formatTime2 = formatTime( ($line =~ /,(\d:\d*:\d*)/g)[2] );
    $formatTime3 = formatTime( ($line =~ /,(\d:\d*:\d*)/g)[3] );
    $formatTime4 = formatTime( ($line =~ /,(\d:\d*:\d*)/g)[4] );
    $formatTime5 = formatTime( ($line =~ /,(\d:\d*:\d*)/g)[5] );
    $formatTime6 = formatTime( ($line =~ /,(\d:\d*:\d*)/g)[6] );

    print $formatTime0."\t".$formatTime1."\t".$formatTime2."\t".$formatTime3."\t".$formatTime4."\t".$formatTime5."\t".$formatTime6."\n";
}

close $OUTPUT;

sub formatTime {
    my $time2format = $_[0];

    my (@temp)  = ($time2format =~ /(\d).*(\d\d).*(\d\d)/);

    my $seconds = $temp[2];
    my $minutes = $temp[1];
    my $hours   = $temp[0];

    if ($minutes > 0) {
        $minutes = $minutes * 60;
    }
    if ($hours > 0) {
        $hours = $hours * 3600;
    }

    my $timeINsec = $hours + $minutes + $seconds;
    return $timeINsec;
}
```

Comment: Hint: Turn `warnings` back on. Turning it off is never a good idea. It just hides your errors, it doesn't remove them.

Comment: I see why you turned them off. This many warnings should not tell you "Oh, I should turn warnings off", it should tell you "I must be doing something wrong."

Comment: Whenever you are about to code scalar variables called, in this case, `$formatTime0` through `$formatTime6`, you should think of using an array instead. If you declare `@formatTime` you can then use `$formatTime[0]` through `$formatTime[6]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code uses an *executable* replacement string to calculate the seconds from each time field.

Setting `$^I = '.orig'` makes Perl keep a backup of the original file in a file with the same name but with `.orig` appended to it.

The program expects the path to the input file as a parameter on the command line, so it should be run like this

```
perl format_time.pl mydata.txt
```

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$^I = '.orig';

while (<>) {
  s{ \b (\d{1,2}) : (\d{1,2}) : (\d{1,2}) \b }{ ($1 * 60 + $2) * 60 + $3 }gxe;
  print;
}
```

**output**

```
Column,Column,Column,Column,Column,Column,Column,Column,Column
1408319018,28,0,60,0,376,NA:NA:NA,452,480
1408313536,126,1,60,0,380,NA:NA:NA,460,586
1408319031,24,0,67,0,426,NA:NA:NA,510,534
1408319018,141,1,54,0,37,NA:NA:NA,111,252
1408319037,6673,1,73,1,1089,NA:NA:NA,1181,7854
1408319031,7098,1,55,0,18,NA:NA:NA,90,7188
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Please explain you answer.

Comment: The Power of the Perl's dark side...one liners. I second the explication part. Do you mind explaining that one line, I kind of get the jist of what you are doing... I think.

Comment: @sSmacKk: That isn't a one-liner: I detest them. The terminal command runs a *program*, complete with `strict` and `warnings`. If you mean the subtitution statement then I don't know what to explain. What do you want to know?

Comment: I've taken a look at your substitute line, played around with it and now I understand what is going on. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using a function to turn one of your tuples into what you want.

Then just cut away the beginning number and let this function do its job on each of the tuples.

Here is my take on it:

```
open my $out, "file.txt";
my @lines;
while ( my $line = <$out> ){    

    next unless $line =~s /^\d+,//; # remove beginning number, skip Column line

    my @tuples = split( ",",$line ); # I kept the N/A values, to discard:
    # my @tuples = grep{ $_ !~ /[a-z]/i }split( ",",$input );

    @tuples = map { tuple_to_seconds( $_ ) }@tuples;

    push @lines, join(",", @tuples ); 
    # I printed with ",", choose what you like best
}
close $out;
open $out, ">file.txt";
print $out join("\n", @lines );
close $out;

sub tuple_to_seconds {
    # takes a tuple and returns N/A for N/A, seconds for a valid number tuple
    my $tuple = shift;
    return "N/A" if $tuple =~ /[a-z]/i;
    my ( $h,$m,$s ) = split( ":", $tuple );

    return $h*3600+$m*60+$s;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain where you actually print back to the file? is it just the print join() thing? Can you explain what happens here if this is it ? Thanks

Comment: Sorry. Edited to print to file. I misread the question at first and did not tackle that. I am saving each line now, then printing it in one go.

Comment: Mainly, I first attempted to make your code more readable and work with warnings on, which I always have on, and would suggest you to keep on as well. They rarely do not help.

Comment: @sSmacKk Try this and see how it works: `perl -pe's/(?<![^,])(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)(?![^,])/$1*3600+$2*60+$3/ge;' yourfile.csv`

Comment: @bytepusher You're adding newline twice. Also, why postpone the print? Not really any point in doing that.

Comment: removed the double newline, thank you. I like to have the reading and writing separate, but I suppose you are correct. To do the job, your one-liner is probably best.

Comment: @bytepusher Shortest is not always best.